# Using Reflection to Save Winform Control States such as CheckBoxes c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, field

I'm trying to use reflection to save states of controls on a winform, but am getting a null reference on the info = myType.GetField... line

This is the saving function which works by saving a list as a string.
eg. cbSetMyParameter,false,cbSetAnother,true

```
private void save_states()
{
    c = GetAll(this, typeof(CheckBox));
    string[] splits = "";
    foreach (CheckBox cb in c) { splits += cb.Name + ',' + cb.Checked.ToString() + ','; }
    Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxStates = splits;
}
```

I then parse the string and wish to use references to set the checkboxes,
but I'm getting a null when I try to use reflection to retrieve a reference to the control

```
private void get_state()
{
    Type myType = this.GetType();
    splits = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBoxStates.Split(',');
    for (cnt=0; cnt < splits.Count()/2; cnt += 2)
    {
        // Get Method Information.
        FieldInfo info = myType.GetField(splits[cnt], BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetField ); 
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)info.GetValue(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `splits[cnt]` is the root cause. You need to debug and check if `splits[cnt]` actually has any value during each iteration.

Comment: In most scenarios you should avoid reflection. Most likely your design is the problem and focus on that instead of using reflection as a solution to the bad design.

Comment: splits[cnt] is not the problem. I have doubled checked the string returned is correct.